# javascript dynamic array creation with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create dynamic array while selecting values from various select boxes.
So I want the created array's  *key and value* should be the *value and text* of as selected.

for example below are three select boxes for Name, grade and age.

```
 Name           grade       age
---------      ---------   ---------
 Jack            A          12
 Sam             B          13
 Jessy           A          11
```

I tried the below code:

```
   <script>
    var data = [];
    $('.filter_select').change(function() {
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();   
    });
    </script>
```

But I am not able to iterate the created array for using $.each(data, function() {});

Whenever I do selecting any of the three select boxes the array should be look like this and can be iterated using $.each

```
var data = []
data['Name'] = 'Sam'
data['grade'] = 'A'
data['age'] = '12'
```

Any help could lead right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var data = {};` if you only need key/value pairs and don't need array capabilities. Iterating properties could be done like this:

```
for (var property in data) {
    // your code accessing data[property]
}
```

Comment: don't forget the check for `data.hasOwnProperty(property)`.